# Нужна помощь с SQL запросом на сортировку

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Товарищи! Выручайте. Затуп какой то словил:
Написать запрос, возвращающий на каждого пользователя (member_id) по три самых дорогих (order_amount) заказа (order_id) в порядке убывания суммы заказов (order_amount)
Есть таблицы tbl_member (в которой member_id) и tbl_order( в которой order_id, order_amount, order_fk_member_id)

Comment: [Посмотрите как можно сделать Ваш запрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: используйте оконные функции для ранжирования строк в группа, и потом подзапрос/cte для выборки строк с нужным числом строк в группе.

Comment: `mysql`, `sql-server` - какой из тегов лишний?